# Simple SELECT query over denormalize data

Tags: mysql, postgresql, select, denormalized

The movie lens data have denormalized genres:

```
movie1  ACTION|ADVENTURE
movie2  ACTION|ADVENTURE|DRAMA
...
```

Is it possible to write a simple SQL to get the normalized movie-genres:

```
movie1  ACTION
movie1  ADVENTURE
movie2  ACTION
...
```

Suppose I'm doing this in MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: Which of those 2 databases are you using?  The answer for splitting values to multiple rows is different for each...

Comment: Let's say PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `PostgreSQL`, you can use `unnest` with `string_to_array`:

```
select name, unnest(string_to_array(genres, '|'))
from movies;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/024cc/2)

Comment: Nice solution.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess MySQL has no such function?